# SSRS report arranging rows to columns

Tags: reporting-services, report

[image]

I need to generate this kind of (please see the image) report in SSRS, and I wrote below 2 SQL's

1. Active Appointments created by Online and Call center
2. Cancelled Appointments by Online and Call center

   with cte as
   (
   select
   ATS.[Description] as AppointmentSource, AST.AppointmentStatusName,
   Month(A.Appointmentdate) as MonthNumber,
   Count(A.AppointmentID) as NumberOfAppointments
   from
   Appointment A
   inner join AppointmentStatus AST ON AST.AppointmentStatusID = A.AppointmentStatusID
   inner join AppointmentSource ATS ON ATS.AppointmentSourceID = A.AppointmentSourceID
   where A.AppointmentDate between '01/01/2020' and '12/31/2020'
   AND ATS.AppointmentSourceID in (1,3)
   AND A.AppointmentStatusID = 1 -- Active
   Group by Month(A.AppointmentDate), ATS.[Description], AST.AppointmentStatusName

   UNION

   select
   ATS.[Description] as AppointmentSource, AST.AppointmentStatusName, Month(A.Appointmentdate) as MonthNumber,
   Count(A.AppointmentID) as NumberOfAppointments
   from
   Appointment A
   inner join AppointmentStatus AST ON AST.AppointmentStatusID = A.AppointmentStatusID
   inner join AppointmentSource ATS ON ATS.AppointmentSourceID = A.AppointmentSourceID
   where A.AppointmentDate between '01/01/2020' and '12/31/2020'
   AND ATS.AppointmentSourceID in (1,3)
   AND A.AppointmentStatusID = 2 -- Cancelled
   Group by Month(A.AppointmentDate), ATS.[Description], AST.AppointmentStatusName
   )

   select AppointmentSource, MonthNumber, NumberOfAppointments, AppointmentStatusName
   from cte
   order by AppointmentSource, AppointmentStatusName asc, MonthNumber

How to arrange the results by Month in the SSRS report ?
Is there a better way to write the SQL and arrange in SSRS report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the actual SQL for now (it would be better to show the results of this rather than the t-sql)...

I think you have enough to build the report, with the exception of the Year which you don't appear to be returning. Once you have corrected this...

1. Create a new report and create your dataset as normal
2. Add a Matrix (not a table) to your report.
3. Add 2 Row Groups first goruped by Year and the second (child group) grouped by AppointmentSource
4. Add a column group, grouped by MonthNumber
5. Choose NumberOfAppointments as the value

That's it, you should get the results as above more or less.

Comment: Thank you Alan, it worked. but how to get Total Scheduled & Cancelled Appointments?

Comment: You need to ask a new question to avoid this one 'drifting'. When you do, make sure you show your 1. report design 2. Row and column groups with details of what they are grouped by 3. Sample data from your dataset. I'm sure somebody will be able to help even if I don't see the question soon.